# Find the combinations that add up to a number, followed by the next number until 0 - in R

Tags: r

I am trying to create a matrix of all the combinations that add up to a number followed by the combinations that add up to the next number until 0. For example

```
Input: N = 3
Output:
[1,]3 0
[2,]2 1
[3,]1 1 1
[4,]2 0
[5,]1 1
[6,]1 0
[7,]0
```

My question is, is there a package in R that can do this? or do I have to write my own function?

I would really appreciate any help or guidance on this. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure of the utility of writing a package that does this one homework piece. (Whether or not this is actual homework for you, it really looks like it.)

Comment: [arrangements](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arrangements/index.html) seems relevant since it can generate integer partitions. I found that by perusing [CRAN Task Views](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/), which is a very useful resource when looking for packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have figured out the solution using the library *partitions*.

```
library(partitions)
n=7
df = t(as.matrix(blockparts(rep(n,n),n, include.fewer = FALSE))) # create a transposed matrix with the possible combinations
indx <- !duplicated(t(apply(df, 1, sort))) # find non - duplicates in sorted rows
df[indx, ] # select only the non - duplicates according to that index
```